# not metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In Munkres, section 30, exercise 6 is this:

Show that $R_{l}$ and $I^2_0$ are not metrizable.

I guess $R_{l}$ is lower limit topology, and $I^2_0$ is an ordered square. and here, how to prove they are **not metrizable?**

I read section 30 and 21 which is about the metric topology, got no clue.

According to the definition of "metrizable", I have to show that they have no metric, but then, I don't know why the usual metric(absolute value) is not a metric for them.

Comment: The usual metric would generate the usual topology......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that
$$(\mbox{separable $+$ metrizable} ) \Rightarrow \mbox{second countable}$$
and show that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is separable ($\mathbb{Q}$ is dense) and not second countable. Conclude that $\mathbb{R}_l$ is not metrizable.

Secondly, show that $I^2_0$ is compact, but it has an infinite sequence with no convergent subsequence. This means that $I^2_0$ is not metrizable.

Comment: AKA [Urysohn's metrization theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UrysohnsMetrizationTheorem.html)